# Contain Output in a List

Tags: python, list, unicode

For my below code everything is working correctly, however I am trying to store my output in a list and I can't figure out how to do so. I tried to create an empty list and append the output to that list but it did not work. Any help would be great!

```
sample_photo_rep["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]
for sample_tags_list in sample_photo_rep["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
    print [sample_tags_list['raw'].decode('utf-8')]

current output: 
[u'Nature']
[u'Mist']
[u'Mountain']

correct output: [u'nature', u'mist', u'mountain']
```

Comment: How did you create the empty list and append because that what I did in my answer and it works

Comment: It would be better to tag this question python-2.7, given that I assume it is the case. Unicode string handling is very different between python 2 and python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop, you're printing a list containing a single element, i.e. `[u'Nature']`, `[u'Mountain']`, etc.

If you remove the enclosing braces, i.e. `[sample_tags_list['raw'].decode('utf-8')]` to `sample_tags_list['raw'].decode('utf-8')`, you should just get the string.

Not sure why your append didn't work, as

```
output = []
for sample_tags_list in sample_photo_rep["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
  output.append(sample_tags_list['raw'].decode('utf-8'))
```

should do the trick. A list comprehension would accomplish the same thing as in the answer from @abccd; both give the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use list comprehension like this:

```
print [sample_tags_list['raw'].decode('utf-8') for sample_tags_list in sample_photo_rep["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]]
```

In place of your `for loop`. This is by far still the most preferred way of doing this. You can see the [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps) for a simple example of using list comps.

Answer (score 0):

declare an empty list at the top of your code like this:

```
tags = []
```

Then, instead of printing it out in your `for loop` append it to the list:

```
for sample_tags_list in sample_photo_rep["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
    tags.append([sample_tags_list['raw'].decode('utf-8')])
```

Then tags should be this:

```
[u'nature', u'mist', u'mountain']
```

**Further Reading**

Info on appending to lists: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm

Info on lists in general: 
https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists